# how to change the data type of a field using peewee in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, orm, peewee

lease help me figure it out. I created this class for a table in a database.

```py
class ProfileAdditionalField(peewee.Model):
    profile = peewee.ForeignKeyField(RpProfile, on_delete='cascade')
    item = peewee.ForeignKeyField(AdditionalField, on_delete='cascade')
    is_allowed = peewee.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        database = db
        primary_key = peewee.CompositeKey('profile', 'item')
```

when I try to modify the RpProfile table, all the entries from the ProfileAdditionalField table become deleted. I think the problem is in setting "on_delete = cascade"

```py
    playhouse_migrate.migrate(
        migrator.add_column('RpProfile', 'show_link',
                            peewee.BooleanField(default=False)),
    )
```

I use SQLite, and the migrator.alter_column_type command does not work in it. I can’t even change the setting so that the data is no longer deleted automatically.
How to add a new field to the RpProfile table without deleting data from the ProfileAdditionalField table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sqlite has limited support for altering columns. This is well-documented:

https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html

You might try disabling foreign-key constraints in sqlite (`pragma foreign_keys=0`) before doing any changes. In order to do anything beyond simply adding a new column in sqlite, peewee has to create a temp table with the desired schema, migrate everything over, then delete the old table and rename the temp table.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I didn’t think the solution would be so simple.
in peewee only need is disable it when open data base 

peewee.SqliteDatabase(db_filename, pragmas={'foreign_keys': 0}